# Need a general way of testing alerts in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

There are hundreds of alerts in a JSON file.

I have to write a test to check if the alert is set or not.

For ex:

```
if alert.INVALID_CELL_IN_THIS_MARKET.set:
    return "INVALID_CELL_IN_THIS_MARKET alert is set"
else:
    return "INVALID_CELL_IN_THIS_MARKET alert is clear"
```

So is there any way that I can check the alerts with any text (instead of  `INVALID_CELL_IN_THIS_MARKET`)

So something like: `if alert.any_string.set`

Comment: please edit with a snippet from the JSON

Comment: I don't see any JSON.

Comment: What is the structure of the JSON file ? Please add  a sample structure of your alert message.

Comment: {"code": "CELL_BLOCKED",
     "format": "Cell {cell.name} blocked",
     "severity": "INFO"}

Answer (score 0):

You Could check the start and end of the string

```
def startsandendswith(main_str):
    return main_str.startswith("alert.") and main_str.endswith(".set")

startsandendswith("alert.any_string.set")
```